# How to insert the values in one table by getting the id from other table

Tags: sql

I want to add a seprate popup for every user from the tbl_users in the tbl_pop_up_messages. For example, If I have 50 users in tbl_users, 50 rows should be added in the tbl_pop_up_messages against every user.S that, every logged in user will see the popup and the popup will be deactivated after the clic.My conern is only to add the rows. Kindly, guide.

```
SELECT user_id FROMt bl_users;
INSERT INTO tbl_pop_up_messages (user_id, popup_text, active) 
VALUES  ('3', 'Pop Up Text', '1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_pop_up_messages(user_id, popup_text, active) 
    SELECT  u.user_id, 'Pop Up Text', '1'
    FROM tbl_users u;
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with an `INSERT INTO SELECT`, like below, provided you have a table with popup messages that you want to be added to each user:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_pop_up_messages (user_id, popup_text, active)
SELECT usr.user_id
    , pmt.popup_text
    , 1 
FROM tbl_users usr
    cross join popup_messages_table pmt
```

Alternatively, you can use a more .. "direct" and long approach, in case you don't have a popup messages table, like below:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_pop_up_messages (user_id, popup_text, active)
SELECT usr.user_id
    , pmt.popup_text
    , 1 
FROM tbl_users usr
    cross join (select 'Pop Up Text' popup_text
               union all
               select '2nd Pop Up Text'
               union all
               select '3rd Pop Up Text'
               -- and so on until you reach X messages or how many you want for each user
              ) pmt
```

If you need to insert only one popup text message for each user, then:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_pop_up_messages (user_id, popup_text, active)
SELECT usr.user_id, 'Pop Up Text', '1'
FROM tbl_users
```

Comment: Because 1 is always equals to 1

Comment: Why don't you use a `cross join` instead of the `left join` with the "always true" join condition?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess you're right, but in the end it would be the same result. I'm curious if it would make a difference in the execution plan (a cross join vs. a left join on 1 = 1)

Comment: No it would not make a difference - but it's always better to state your intention by using the appropriate syntax.